# Monitor Vyatta router VPN through SNMP

Tags: router, vpn, snmp, vyatta

I would like to monitor/manage VPN /Tunnel for Vyatta router 5600 through SNMP . Can't find mib or specific OID for the Vyatta router 5600. ? 
Please answer with Mib or SNMP OID .
Thanks in advance

Comment: A tunnel interface is an interface. I think you just need to use what you would for an interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you . But I also need to track down Rx and Tx in the tunnel.

Comment: I don't know if your device supports it, but the proper protocol for something like that is NetFlow (IPFIX).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No proper MIB is there for Vyatta 5600 . So I  have started to use TCP mib.

Comment: You can post that in an answer and accept it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A google found this "Supported MIBs" in Vyatta Remote Management Reference Guide

http://www.brocade.com/content/html/en/configuration-guide/vrouter5600_3.5R1_RemoteManagement/GUID-2789A59B-7B4B-47E5-98F1-EECE7E8C6005.html

Answer (score -1):

There is no proper MIB for Vyatta 5600. So I started using TCP MIB.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't. SNMP is and has always been a crappy protocol. Use the REST (HTTP) API. See [Brocade's REST API Intro](http://www.brocade.com/content/html/en/vrouter5600/40r1/vrouter-40r1-remoteaccessapi/GUID-CC5898D6-AC14-424A-8199-DDEAF4BEB401.html):

> The Brocade vRouter Remote Access API 2.0 enables remote command
>   execution on a Brocade vRouter over HTTPS by using a simple, coherent,
>   and stateless interface. In addition to accessing the standard set of
>   operational and configuration commands, the API provides process
>   control and management features.
>
> The API adheres to Representational State Transfer (REST) principles
>   where possible, and uses the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format
>   for data representation. Version 2.0 of the API largely replaces the
>   original XML-based Brocade vRouter Remote Access API 1.0.
>
> The API interacts with the Brocade vRouter through an operational
>   mode/configuration mode model. The API modes are closely analogous to
>   the corresponding CLI modes but include additional capability to
>   support session and process management.
>
> Commands that return response bodies provide JSON-formatted output,
>   unless otherwise noted.

Comment: This "Network Engineering" SE site provides strong evidence that "network engineers" are going extinct. Casting my pearls to swine here....